# What should be the mentioned in the host in django if I'm running redis in a docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker, redis

```
'host': 'localhost',
'port': 6379,
```

This is a part of the redis configuration that I am using. I have created a DockerFile for my app. I want to eventually test it with running a separate redis docker container without using docker-compose.

What should I mention in the 'host' part of the configuration? Is it enough if I mention the following in Django settings.py?

```
'host': <Name_of_redis_container>,
'port': 6379,
```

Comment: The two containers need to be on the same `docker network create` network, and then you can use the containers' names as hostnames.  You might read through [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) in the Docker documentation, focusing on "user-defined bridges".

Answer (score 1):

**you must put 0.0.0.0** for global accessing I mean you can access the site around the world but don't forget to forward the port you've selected !